# Can't export table into Excel 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-excel

I was watching http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast about exporting tables and follow all steps.

I have in my aplication.rb:

```
 require 'csv'
```

Added MimeType in mime_types.rb:

```
          Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```

My controller:

```
def index

if params[:report] && params[:report][:start_date] && params[:report][:end_date]
 start_date = params[:report][:start_date]
 end_date = params[:report][:end_date]
 @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where(:created_at => start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.csv { send_data @financial_reports.to_csv }
  format.xls
  format.json { render json: @financial_reports }
 end
end
```

end

In my model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  all.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
```

end

and finally - links in view:

```
<%if @financial_reports%>  
 Download:
 <%= link_to "CSV", financial_reports_path(format: "csv") %> |
<%= link_to "Excel", financial_reports_path(format: "xls") %>
 ...
 <%end%>
```

when I'm clicking on Excel link giving me error:

```
         undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

but I DO see data in table(html)!

Also, when I'm clicking CSV:

```
    Template is missing
```

I restarted my application when added something in configuration files.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code

```
@financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports.where(:created_at => start_date.to_date..end_date.to_date)
```

you are filtering the financial reports based on start date and end date. It will return you a collection of financial_reports. So you can not directly call  @financial_reports.to_csv. Another way you can send it as a parameter of a method like

```
 format.csv { send_data FinancialReport.to_csv(@financial_reports) }
```

and in the model

```
def self.to_csv(reports,options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << column_names
  reports.each do |product|
    csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
end
```

Template is missing - error will happen when you dont have a corresponding view file

Check whether you have the /app/views/products/index.xls.erb file as specified in your reference http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

Comment: @Mathi,thanks for help, but now I'm getting error 

`unexpected end` and after reload - `undefined method key?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Previous errors still there( Even when I set condition `where(:created_at => "1/08/2012".to_date.."10/08/2012".to_date)`

Comment: I rewrited code using another article, but I don't know how to pass params(